# Show that $O(n)$, the set of orthogonal $n \times n$ matrices, is not connected

Tags: general-topology, matrices, connectedness, orthogonal-matrices

I want to show that $O(n)$, the set of orthogonal $n \times n$ matrices is not connected.

---

I know that a connected space $X$ does not split into disjoint non-empty open subsets, so to prove $O(n)$ is *not* connected I need to find disjoint non-empty open subsets that partition $O(n)$. But I have not been able to get any

---

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Hint: The determinant map from $O(n)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hint :**

The function $f:O(n)\to \{-1,1\}$ defined by $f(A)=\operatorname{ det}(A)$ is continuous.

Comment: It is not a bijection. It is, however, surjective.

Comment: @ James ) Sorry...Now fixed it..

Comment: @S.Panja-1729 Thanks for the response. Is this correct: $f: O(n) \rightarrow$ {$-1,1$} is continuous, hence the inverse image of every open set is open. Hence the inverse image of {-1} and {1} are open in O(n). These are disjoint in O(n) since {-1} and {1} are disjoint. And because f is a surjection, they partition O(n).
So, since O(n) partitions into disjoint non-empty open subsets, it is not connected.

Comment: Or you can just say that if $O(n)$ were connected, and since image of a connected set is connected under a continuous map, ${-1,1}$ is also connected in $\mathbb{R}$ which is not true as we know.